# Maven JavaDoc --enable-preview

Tags: maven, javadoc

How do I set --enable-preview for JavaDoc in Maven? I have found an answer for Gradle and for Maven compile, but not JavaDoc.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <release>14</release>
                <compilerArgs>
                    --enable-preview
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: have you tried https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#additionalOptions ?

Comment: <additionalOptions>--enable-preview</additionalOptions> did not work, still get errors on Java 14 preview features.

Comment: weird, with that config + Java 8 I get the message `Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - invalid flag: --enable-preview`, so it is recognized. Did you configure it as report-plugin or build-plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
<configuration>
    <release>14</release>
    <additionalOptions>--enable-preview</additionalOptions>
...
```

Comment: I tried this and I received an error saying "--enable-preview must be used with --source or --target".  So, to get it to work, I had to also add `<source>17</source>` and `<target>17</target>`